# unique_ptr deleter trick: which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr

I was going through [this particular SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45353838/6101143) on how to save memory space for custom deleter pointer. At the bottom of the answer, it provides a custom written version in C++11.

After dozens of minutes trying to understand the code, I discover some compiler inconsistencies among the Big 3, where clang compiles, while the other two complain with compiler errors. ([Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4MrTx7zYz))

---

My code is a little different from the other SO answer. Here it goes:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <class T, T t>
struct val {
    constexpr operator typename decay<T>::type() const noexcept {
        return t;
    }
};

using default_free = val<decltype(free), free>;

int main(void) {
    unique_ptr<void, default_free> p(malloc(42));
    cout << p.get() << endl;
    p.reset();
    cout << p.get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Please correct me if I'm wrong here. The way I see it, the trick is to provide a constexpr function that can cast an object of type `default_delete` to a function pointer with the value of `t` (`free` as its instantiation).

So the question: which compiler is correct?

Comment: GCC seem to not implement https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#8

Comment: `val<decltype(&free), &free>` works [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sTK1G3Mrf)

Comment: And as you are in C++17, `template <auto t>
struct val;` and `val<&free>` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vW6MPbTa9).

Comment: It looks like gcc trunk works, meaning it should be fixed in the next official version: https://godbolt.org/z/r445dY6hM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a gcc bug, and a completely different MSVC bug.

gcc cannot do this:

```
template <typename T, T t> struct foo {};
```

when instantiated with a function type. `T` has to be a template parameter for this bug to be triggered; `template <void t(void*) noexcept>` works.

```
template <typename T, T* t> struct foo {};
```

fixes the problem.

MSVC eats either of the previous constructs perfectly well, but it cannot use `free` as a non-type template argument. (Other standard C library functions as well.) A simple solution is to use a qualified name (either `::free` or `std::free`, both work). Wrapping `free` in another function also fixes the problem. This is because MSVC apparently thinks (in this context) that `::free` and `std::free` are different functions, and cannot disambiguate. One can reproduce this with no standard library:

```
void foo(void*);

namespace moo {
  using ::foo;
}

using namespace moo;
```

Now plain `foo` cannot be used as a template parameter.

Comment: Not sure from which C++ version but all STL functions are to be addressed as callables - so one cannot cast them into function pointers legally.

Comment: @ALX23z:Does it apply to C functions too?

Comment: `val<decltype(&free), &free>` seems a better fix.